# cannot modify micro sd

Tags: memory, android, micro-sd-card

I have a Silicon Power microSDHC card (16 GB class 10).
The card is split into two partitions: 14GB FAT32 and 1GB EXT2, both are primary partitions (For use link2sd app in android). This worked previously. Now when I've been trying to remove or edit files on my SD Card I get no errors, but when I unplug it and plug it again nothing changed. The old files are there and the new ones disappeared.

I've been trying to format or delete and create partitions with MiniTool Partition Wizard windows app (or anothes apps), it's done without errors, but when I unplug it and plug it again, nothing changed.

I've tried:

1. windows format
2. SDFormatter windows app
3. in android mobile
4. HDD Low Level Format.

Answer (score 1):

Download and boot MagicDisc. Delete everything including partition tables, and then use gParted to format the MicroSD using a FAT32 filesystem, allocating all the size to a single partition. That should solve the problem.